# Select specific columns plus avg and max using the aliased chainable convenience methods in datastax Java driver for Cassandra

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

Say I have this general SQL query using the convenience methods of the driver:

```
statement = select().from(keyspace, table)
            .where(eq("fieldx", var1))
            .and(eq("fieldy", var2))
            .orderBy(asc("fieldz"));
return client.getSession().execute(statement);
```

and how would I rework the query above to support this kind of CQL/SQL:

```
select fielda, fieldb, avg(fieldc), max(fielde) from ...
```

using IntelliJ, I notice after the `select().` I can only chain it to append a `column()` to filter query for specific columns, but I don't see available option for `avg()` and `max()`. Looking at the JavaDocs, looks like those should exist? Or I'm not using the right `select()` method where it's available (I'm a novice to Cassandra and this Java driver). Using goto declaration from the IDE, I see the `select()` method leads to the QueryBuilder class's static `select()` method that returns a `SelectionOrAlias()` method which matches up with the JavaDocs for available methods from that class.

For imports these are the non-custom classes that are imported w.r.t. the driver:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Statement;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import static com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.*;
```

what am I missing for the right query setup?

Comment: on a related note, searching the web, unless I'm not searching right, seems the QueryBuilder examples only show `select()` and `select().all()` and use of where, and, etc. filtering but don't seem to find examples chaining up avg, max, count, and columns selection. Wonder why is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common aggregate methods in CQL have been available in `QueryBuilder` since 3.3.0 / dse 1.3.0 ([JAVA-1443](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1443)).  Here's how you would use them:

```java
import com.datastax.driver.core.Statement;

import static com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Statement statement = select("fielda",
                "fieldb",
                avg("fieldc"),
                max("fielde"))
                .from("tbl");

        System.out.println(statement);
    }
}
```

This yields: `SELECT fielda,fieldb,avg(fieldc),max(fielde) FROM tbl;`

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. A follow up Q: is it simple to just add on aliasing like "avg(fieldx) as fieldx1" or is there a specific syntax for that? I should have included that in original question.

Comment: You can use QueryBuilder.alias for that, i.e.: alias(avg("fieldx"), "fieldx1");

Comment: Does alias work for fcall? Or what's the equivalent in that case? It looks like the repo I work with uses the older driver.

Comment: Trying the example for older driver, w/o any aliasing, IDE/compile reports error in data type mismatch: `Error:(30, 21) java: method select in class com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String[]; found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object; reason: varargs mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String` Problem is with adding the fcall.

Comment: It looks like `select` doesn’t take `Object` arguments (which `fcall` and the other aggregate methods return) in the version of the driver you are using, so it looks like you need to upgrade to get that capability

Comment: Thanks, I'm switching to using prepared statements for now.